# PreparedStatement on oracle and index usage

Tags: performance, oracle, indexing, escaping, prepared-statement

I have a table like this one in Oracle:

```
create table suppliers(name varchar2(100));
```

With its corresponding index on `upper(name)`:

```
create index supplier_name_upper_idx on suppliers(upper(name));
```

I would like to populate an autocomplete through AJAX, getting the information from a Servlet running JDBC queries.

This works:

```
PreparedStatement ps = 
   conn.prepareStatement(
       "select * from suppliers where upper(name) like ?"
   );
ps.setString(1, 'something%');
```

The problem is, as far as I know, `PreparedStatement` won't use the index because it can't know, at statement compile time, whether the parameter is going to be `'something%'` (being able to get performance advantage from index) or `'%something%'` (not being able to get performance advantage from index).

So, my question is:

1. Should I use a `Statement` instead? If so, what's the best way to escape the input parameter (since it will come from an AJAX request)
2. Is there something I can use to make the `PreparedStatement` to use the index?

Answer (score 1):

I think prepared statement is better because you will have fewer parses on server side, and as a result fewer 'latches : library cache'.

`SELECT /*+ INDEX suppliers(supplier_name_upper_idx) */ * from suppliers ....` should make statement  use index "supplier_name_upper_idx".